# rails coffeescript - how to include a javascript file (in development)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, assets

I have the following coffeescript file that I wish to include:

```
app/assets/javascripts/groups.js.coffee
```

I have an application file - `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` that has:

```
//= require_tree .
```

My `views/layouts/application.html.haml` file includes:

```
= javascript_include_tag :defaults
= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"
```

My page does not seem to have the `groups.js` file

It does get the  `jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js` but I'm not sure where from.

I tried putting `= javascript_include_tag "groups.js"` in
`views/layouts/application.html.haml` and restarted the server and that *does* then have a `groups.js` referenced in the header but clicking on that actual file (in the browser show view) shows this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>
  <style>
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #333; }

    body, p, ol, ul, td {
      font-family: helvetica, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:   13px;
      line-height: 18px;
    }

    pre {
      background-color: #eee;
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 11px;
    }

    a { color: #000; }
    a:visited { color: #666; }
    a:hover { color: #fff; background-color:#000; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Routing Error</h1>
<p><pre>No route matches [GET] &quot;/javascripts/groups.js&quot;</pre></p>



</body>
</html>
```

and I also tried putting `//= require_tree .` in
`app/assets/javascript/application.js` but just got an error messages that the file wasn't found (`javascript/groups.js`)

I also tried `rake assets:precompile` but that gives a strange error about `Please install the pg adapter: gem install activerecord-pg-adapter` but trying *that* gives `ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem activerecord-pg-adapter (>= 0) in any repository`

I have no idea what that is about as the application is working full both locally and on remote, using the database with no problem, so it's probably a separate issue.  I mention it in case you suggest `rake assets:precompile` is needed, however to have the assets used in development this should not be an issue (I think).

Originally the app was rails 2.3.8 but now it 3.1.8 - hmm, this be may key if assets came in 3.2+

Comment: Add `=javascript_include_tag "application"` and check by restarting the server if it works for you

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and still got the `Action Controller: Exception caught` error

Comment: Then guess the coffeescript file is not being compiled afterall. Why don't you create a simple `group.js` file in `app/assets/javascripts` with anything (say `alert("FOO")`) and then check if that file is available.

Comment: Upgraded to rails 2.3.8 didn't help though.  the groups.js file is very simple (only 5 lines long).

Comment: Can we discuss this at : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-on-rails ?

Comment: Thaks but actually have to run.  Will probably post the '2nd issue' as a separate question.  Thanks for your help, I +1'd your comments :
)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to make sure that:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

is present in `application.rb`.

Also, the following link might be helpful:  http://pivotallabs.com/giving-rails-2-the-asset-pipeline!

Comment: This app was originally developed in rails 2.3.8 so I put there is some setting that I need to change that would be pre-set on a new app

Comment: @MichaelDurrant ahh gotcha. Would you maybe be willing to post the dev env config?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant also, which version of rails are you using now?

Comment: rails 3.1.8 and I think that is the problem.   I've changed it to rails 3.2.8 and trying that

Comment: Is `config.assets.enabled = true` present in application.rb under the config directory?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant fingers crossed.

Comment: Two things happened - all my css disappeared.... and I got `throw Error("LoadError: cannot load such file -- coffee_script\n  (in /home/durrantm/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker/app/assets/javascripts/groups.js.coffee)")` when trying to view the groups.js file

Comment: Oh no! Have you checked this out by any chance? http://pivotallabs.com/giving-rails-2-the-asset-pipeline/

Comment: resolved the css - had to move all my public/ stuff to assets/  Also had to add in the 'sass' ghem to my Gemfile and bundle... and my css is back!   Great!  Now to check that js file one more time...

Comment: hmmm, css is all back by that file still shows throw Error("LoadError: cannot load such file -- coffee_script\n  (in /home/durrantm/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker/app/assets/javascripts/groups.js.coffee)").

Comment: hadn't tried that link no.  That is useful.  I am probably reproducing the steps here...

Comment: I would suggest posting the config.assets_enabled = true as an answer and also mentioning the link to upgrade.  I will upvote and may also accept it.

Comment: So happy to be doing this using git and in a branch :)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant will do!

Comment: And I believe it! @MichaelDurrant